# Mapbox iOS connect MGLPolyline coordinates right

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, mapbox, mglmapview

In my app I'm showing a path of a satellite's orbit.
I understand I need to normalize the longitude of the coordinate when it crosses the meridian, but I can't seem to fund the correct formula. This results in the effect seen in the image.[image]

Can someone please tell me the code I need to have this fixed?

Comment: You might have better luck receiving help if you include code for others to inspect.